# List of paths to JSON object that mirrors the folder structure

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, content-management-system

I'm building a small folder based cms. I'm using php to extract all the paths of a folder and I want to use javascript to build the website. I know that I could do everything in php, but I'm more fluent in javascript and therefore I'd like to use that instead of php. Anyway with php i get this list:

```
0: {parent: "theater", child: "How_to_be_a_regisseur", text: "Project 1!↵Phasellus a quam non arcu accumsan rhon…ium leo ante, vitae volutpat diam consectetur in."}
1: {parent: "theater", child: "How_to_be_a_regisseur", img: "./content/theater/How_to_be_a_regisseur/img/download.jpeg"}
2: {parent: "theater", child: "How_to_be_a_regisseur", img: "./content/theater/How_to_be_a_regisseur/img/rsz_namibia_will_burrard_lucas_wwf_us_1.jpg"}
4: {parent: "theater", child: "WOOWW", text: "Project 1!↵Phasellus a quam non arcu accumsan rhon…ium leo ante, vitae volutpat diam consectetur in."}
...
12: {parent: "varia", child: "gggggg", text: "Project 1!↵Phasellus a 
13: {parent: "varia", child: "gggggg", img: "./content/varia/gggggg/img/download.jpeg"}
14: {parent: "varia", child: "gggggg", img: "./content/varia/gggggg/img/rsz_namibia_will_burrard_lucas_wwf_us_1.jpg"}
...
20: {parent: "about", child: null, img: "./content/about/img/download.jpeg"}
```

`parent` means the folder, and `child` the sub folder and `img` or `text` the content of that folder.
is there any way to restructure this array into an array of objects with this structure in which all the `parents` become an attribute containing an array of `children` each one of them containing different objects with links to the images or to the text?

```
{
    theater: [
        How_to_be_a_regisseur: {
            img: "path",
            text: "blah blah"
        },
        WOOW: {
            img: "path",
            text: "blah blah"
        }
    ],
    varia:[...{[][]}]
}
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). That is just an array of objects.

Comment: build your object in PHP the way you want it represented in JavaScript and use `json_encode` to serialize the object to JSON and then just consume that in your JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var list = [
                { parent: "theater", child: "How_to_be_a_regisseur", text: "Project 1!↵Phasellus a quam non arcu accumsan rhon…ium leo ante, vitae volutpat diam consectetur in." },
                { parent: "theater", child: "How_to_be_a_regisseur", img: "./content/theater/How_to_be_a_regisseur/img/download.jpeg" },
                { parent: "theater", child: "How_to_be_a_regisseur", img: "./content/theater/How_to_be_a_regisseur/img/rsz_namibia_will_burrard_lucas_wwf_us_1.jpg" },
                { parent: "theater", child: "WOOWW", text: "Project 1!↵Phasellus a quam non arcu accumsan rhon…ium leo ante, vitae volutpat diam consectetur in." },
                { parent: "varia", child: "gggggg", text: "Project 1!↵Phasellus a "},
                { parent: "varia", child: "gggggg", img: "./content/varia/gggggg/img/download.jpeg"},
                { parent: "varia", child: "gggggg", img: "./content/varia/gggggg/img/rsz_namibia_will_burrard_lucas_wwf_us_1.jpg"},
                { parent: "about", child: null, img: "./content/about/img/download.jpeg"}
            ];
var new_list = list.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
    var parent = currentValue.parent;
    var child = currentValue.child;
    if (!accumulator[parent]) {
        accumulator[parent] = [];
    }
    if (!accumulator[parent][child]) {
        accumulator[parent][child] = [];
    }
    accumulator[parent][child].push({
        text: currentValue.text,
        img: currentValue.img
    });
    return accumulator;
}, {});
console.log(new_list);
```

Somehow I restructured it.